# Delete more than one file using unlink

Tags: php, unlink

Hi I got this simple delete script, but I can only get it to delete one file in the folder. I tried some different stuff trying to loop the unlink but it wont work. Does anyone knows how it is done?

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql_get = "SELECT shop.id, shop.overskrift, shop.pris, shop.text, shop_pictures.ShopPictures_id, shop_pictures.shop_pictures_file
            FROM shop INNER JOIN shop_pictures
            ON shop.id = shop_pictures.fk_shop_pictures_shop_id WHERE Id=$id";
$result_get = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_get);
$row = mysqli_fetch_all($result_get);

$sql = "DELETE FROM shop WHERE Id=$id";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

$sql = "DELETE FROM shop_pictures WHERE fk_shop_pictures_shop_id=$id";
if(!empty($row)) {
    foreach($row as $data) {
        unlink('../../img/shop_pictures/'.$data['shop_pictures_file']);
    }
}
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

//header('Location: ../members.php');exit;
```

Comment: So how are you intending to loop through each of the results?

Comment: Thats what im asking help for. i want to loop through the unlink.. i upload 4 images and when i try to delete it with that script it only removes 1 img

Comment: `$pics_being_deleted` isn't defined anywhere in this scripts. It's unclear as to what files you're wanting to delete, and how you're looping through those files.

Comment: Sorry this is how it looks like

unlink('../../img/shop_pictures/'.$row['shop_pictures_file']);

Comment: Fix the code in your question to actually reflect what is there (Minus any sensitive data)

Comment: I just edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is incredibly susceptible to [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) so you may want to address that. However, you need to loop through your results.

`$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_get);` only fetches one result, make sure you use something like this instead:

`$row = mysqli_fetch_all($result_get, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

```
if(!empty($row) {
    foreach($row as $data) {
        unlink('../../img/shop_pictures/'.$data['shop_pictures_file']);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could do something like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_get)) {
    unlink('../../img/shop_pictures/'.$row['shop_pictures_file']);
}
```

That should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Somehow i cant get it to work none of the images in the folder is getting deleted

Comment: It's only going to unlink whatever your results from the query are. Not what files exist in the directory.

Comment: I know it should remove the images that has the fk_shop_pictures_shop_id
as the same as in the shop table

Comment: In the loop, `echo "<img src='../../img/shop_pictures/{$row['shop_pictures_file']}'/>";` What happens? If it doesn't load the images you're trying to delete, the path isn't correct.

Comment: i just took out the header location and it gave me this error

Notice: Undefined index: shop_pictures_file in D:\xampp\htdocs\lmj\login_system\functions\delete.php on line 17

Comment: The header location? More code you didn't include? You're not selecting `shop_pictures_file` anywhere in the query, so it makes sense.

Comment: Yes sorry its been a long day. 
How should i select that in my query?

Comment: I don't know, you tell me. I don't know what table it's in. My only direction is to make sure that you select that column in `$sql_get`

Comment: shop_pictures_file is in the table shop_pictures

Comment: Okay, then add that to your select statement and this will work.

Comment: As you see i did

"shop_pictures.shop_pictures_file"

Its probely cuz you cant see it the code is all the way to the right
idk why it did that

Comment: What is on `line 17`? The error is telling you what's wrong.

Comment: unlink('../../img/shop_pictures/'.$data['shop_pictures_file']);

Comment: Did you change `$row = mysqli_fetch_all($result_get);` as well? Obviously you're making code changes and it's not the same as what is on the question anymore, so this is turning into me trying to help debug code I don't know how it's written anymore.

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($data);` in the loop?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: shop_pictures_file in D:\xampp\htdocs\lmj\login_system\functions\delete.php on line 16

Warning: unlink(../../img/shop_pictures/): Permission denied in D:\xampp\htdocs\lmj\login_system\functions\delete.php on line 16
array(6) { [0]=> string(3) "117" [1]=> string(5) "asdas" [2]=> string(4) "dasd" [3]=> string(5) "asdas" [4]=> string(3) "124" [5]=> string(27) "57c8be7eb49f24.65306143.jpg" } 
Notice: Undefined index: shop_pictures_file in D:\xampp\htdocs\lmj\login_system\functions\delete.php on line 16

Comment: I swore that `mysql_fetch_all` defaulted to both associative and numeric response. Oh well, I fixed that. But the real bugger is that you have permission issues: `Warning: unlink(../../img/shop_pictures/): Permission denied in D:\xampp\htdocs\lmj\login_system\functions\delete.php on line 16` After you fix the `$row` update I made, you'll have to figure out permissions. Good luck!

Comment: The permission wasent the problem is was that 
$row = mysqli_fetch_all($result_get, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

thanks for the help!